# How is the "number of questions per day" calculated in the meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, meta

I'd love to see this site exit from the beta phase and becoming a real site. I've read in the meta (just now) that there's a number of 3.3 questions per day in it and that a healthy site would require 15 of them. I'm asking:

how does the meta site calculate this number? Is it the actual, current value for each single day or does it average over a time interval of x days? In this case, what is the value of x? This would affect the result a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "questions per day" as displayed in [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/german.stackexchange.com) are calculated as the average question count since beta launch, or in the last two weeks, whichever is shorter.

In our case we therefore see the **average daily question count from the last two weeks**.

Also see:

- [Bug in Area 51's questions per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73217/bug-in-area-51s-questions-per-day)
- [Incorrect "questions per day" for beta sites on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96278/incorrect-questions-per-day-for-beta-sites-on-area51)